# Re-tagging merged question

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

So as part of my effort to waste a day and hit the daily rep count the hard way by re-tagging, I came across [Bring Debian to second Position in the GRUB Menu at startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100787/bring-debian-to-second-position-in-the-grub-menu-at-startup) which is a duplicate (no question about that.) and merged (and migrated just to make things fun). Now it is tagged grub which we are trying to kill, and since he is installing a recent debian which uses grub2, I decided to retag it as grub2, but the edit button is grayed out.

So should I flag it, mention it here, or chat?

Comment: Please don't do that many retags in one day. When you do retags, check the [front page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). If it starts showing too many questions edited by you, take a break. Let other questions, especially new questions and questions with new answers, get some attention too.

Answer (score 3):

I would either flag it and use the "other" with custom comment (which happens to be the only option on that question anyway) or mention it in chat.